# Instagram Api Returns "invalid media id" Message When Getting Comments by Media ID

Tags: api, get, request, instagram, instagram-api

When I try to get comments via `GET`request, I take error message which is below. By the way application's Client Status is `Sandbox Mode`.

P.S: My access token is working. I can understand that by changing the token so api returns invalid token message.

**Pure Instagram Media**

https://www.instagram.com/p/BMQjQQggJkH/

**Get API**

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/BMQjQQggJkH/comments?access_token=my_token

**Output**

> {"meta": {"error_type": "APINotFoundError", "error_message": "invalid media id", "code": 400}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BMQjQQggJkH` <- thats not `media-id`, thats media `shortcode`.

First use this end point to get `media-id` from `shortcode`:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/shortcode/D?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

get `data.id` from response and then use this endpoint to get comments:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Comment: Thank you @krisrak